# windows 7 explorer behavior

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

can anyone tell me how i can have my windows explorer launch with the root contents of the c: drive expanded in the left window pane?

i currently have the default location set to my computer, but i would like the root folders under the c drive to automatically show on the left, is this possible?

thx
b

Answer (score 0):

I don't have win7 to test, but in XP (and earlier I think) the command line argument to open in explorer view, selecting C:\ is

```
 explorer ,/e,C:\
```

So you can make a shortcut with this parameter. Hasn't changed the default location, but provides the equivalent effect.

Comment: screenshots here for W7...http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/02/07/trick-to-open-computer-or-documents-as-default-instead-of-libraries-folder-with-windows-explorer-on-windows-7/

Comment: hmm, still not quite what i'm looking for. i'd like xplorer to open with the 'computer' selected and drives seen on right, but on the left pane, would like c drive to be expanded

Answer (score 0):

Nice article here

http://www.maxi-pedia.com/Windows+7+Explorer+default+folder

.